# Convert input to uppercase in a game

Tags: c, arrays, string, uppercase, lowercase

I wrote a very simple Hangman game that requests user input then makes the user guess up to six times.
The first letter of the word is always shown and if the user inputs the same letter that has already been uncovered it is not seen as a mistake,
I want to improve my code to make it accept lowercase input if the hangman string consists of Uppercase letters. 
For example if the input string is "HELLO" and the user sees this H_____ on the console and he inputs lowecase 'e' then the letter should be uncovered and printed as a capital letter as the input string.
So after the user inputs e the output should look like this HE___
However with the way I implemented it just converts all uppercase Letters to lowercase Letters.

How can I make the code accept lowercase userinput and print out Uppercase user input if a Uppercase letter is in the string?

Thanks for any help

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <string.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char hangmanWord[100], tempWord[100];      
    char hangmanOutput[100];                    
    int wrongTry = 6 , matchFound = 0;         
    int tries = 0;                             
    int counter = 0 , position = 0, winner, length , i;
    char alphabetFromUser;
    scanf("%s",hangmanWord);

    getchar();
    length = strlen(hangmanWord);

     for( i = 1; i < length ; i++)
    {   
        hangmanOutput[i] = '_';
        hangmanOutput[length] = '\0';
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)

    {   

        if(i==0){
        printf("%c",hangmanWord[0]);

        }

        printf("%c",hangmanOutput[i]);  //line output 

         if(i==length-1){
             printf("(%d)",tries);
         }

    }

    while(wrongTry != 0)                        /**while loop for exiting the program when no try left**/
    {
        matchFound = 0;
        putchar('\n');
        printf("letter: ");
        scanf("%c",&alphabetFromUser);
        fflush(stdin);
        if (matchFound != 2)
    {
        for(counter=0;counter<length;counter++)    /**for loop to check whether player input alphabet exists or not in the word**/
        {

            if(hangmanWord[counter]>= 'A' && hangmanWord[counter] <= 'Z'){

                hangmanWord[counter] = tolower(hangmanWord[counter]);
                 }

            if(alphabetFromUser==hangmanWord[counter])
             {
               matchFound = 1;
                     }//end of if()
            }//end of

     if(matchFound == 0)                      /**in case of wrong guess**/
        {
             wrongTry--;
             tries++;
        }//en
    else
       {
         for(counter = 0; counter < length; counter++)
             {
                 matchFound = 0;
                 if(alphabetFromUser == hangmanWord[counter])
              {
                 position = counter ;
                 matchFound = 1;
              }//end of if
              if(matchFound == 1)
              {
                 for(i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
                 {
                      if( i == position)
                      {
                          hangmanOutput[i] = alphabetFromUser; /**Put the alphabet at right position**/
                      }
                      else if( hangmanOutput[i] >= 'a' && hangmanOutput[i] <= 'z' ) /** If the position already occupied
                                                                                  by same alphabet then no need to
                                                                                  fill again EASY!! and continue */
                      {
                          continue;
                      }

                      else
                      {
                          hangmanOutput[i] = '_';            /** Put a underscore at not guessed alphabet position **/
                      }
                }

                 tempWord[position] = alphabetFromUser;      /**put the alphabet in another char array to check with the original word**/
                tempWord[length] = '\0';   
                             /**put the NULL character at the end of the temp string**/
                winner = strcmp(tempWord+1,hangmanWord+1);      /**upon True comparison it will return 0**/

                if(winner == 0)                             /**if the player guessed the whole word right then he/she is the WINNER**/
                {
                    for(i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)

    {   
        if(i==0){
        printf("%c",hangmanWord[0]);

        }

        printf("%c",hangmanOutput[i+1]);  //line output  
         if(i==length-1){
             printf("(%d)",tries);
         }
    }     
                    getchar();
                    return 0;
                }//end of inner if
           }//end of outer if
        }//end of for loop
      }//end of else
    } // end of if(matchFound != 2) condition

for(i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
    {   
        if(i==0){
        printf("%c",hangmanWord[0]);

        }

        printf("%c",hangmanOutput[i+1]);  //line output  
         if(i==length-1){
             printf("(%d)",tries);
         }
    }
    getchar();
    }

          if(wrongTry <= 0)                                 /**if the player can not guess the whole word in 5 chaces**/
      {
          putchar('\n');
          printf("DEAD\n");
          return 0;
      }
getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation and remove unneccessary empty lines.

Comment: The `toupper()` function has “upper” in its name to remind you what it does.

Comment: I am aware of the toupper function. But I was thinking I would first check if there is a uppercase letter in the string then use to lower so that I can compare it with the input. But I don't know where I could implement the toupper() function in my code to make the characters big again after the comparison

Comment: Your question is reasonably clear, but it contains unnecessary details. The part of the code that involves the logic of the game is irrelevant to your actual question. You can come up with a *much* shorter question that focuses on how to capitalize input. Please read about how to make a [mcve].

Comment: You convert the input to upper case to match your working text.  You don’t convert your working text to lower case on the off chance that the user entered lower case; they might have entered a capital letter instead.

Comment: *ut I was thinking I would first check if there is a uppercase letter in the string*  [`isupper()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.1.11).

Comment: I don't quite understand. Is the first if clause correct? I should have also mentioned that I am going to assume that the user isn't going to enter any capital letters when trying to uncover the word

Comment: `printf("%c",hangmanOutput[i]);` is a problem when `i==0`.  `hangmanOutput[0]` is not assigned.  Why does prior loop run from 1 instead of 0?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica because the first character is always shown

Comment: senpai, What do you expect `printf("%c",hangmanOutput[i]);` to print when `i==0`?  Review code. `hangmanOutput[0]` is not assigned prior to the print.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you are right , I actually meant to start the loop at one at the  `for(counter=0;counter<length;counter++)` line

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [ascii table](https://www.asciitable.com/), the lower case letters from a-z are from 0x6_, to 0x7_ and the upper case ones from 0x4_ to 0x5_, which means that all we have to do is to toggle off the second bit of the second nibble in order to convert a lowercase letter to an uppercase letter.

(a) a-z are as follows 0110 xxxx, 0111 xxxx

(b) A-Z are as follows 0100 xxxx, 0101 xxxx

Let's assume that we have the character 'a', which is 0110 xxxx. If we use the AND bitwise with 0x5F => 0110 xxxx & 0101 xxxx => 0100 xxxx => 'A'

```
char upper(char ch) {
   return(ch & 0x5F);
}
```

Now that we have the function, we can use it. Looking at your code, you are checking the hangman array twice in case the user has typed in a lower case letter or a uppercase letter so instead of doing that we could do that once

```
 int32_t right_letter;
 int32_t tries;
 int32_t win;

 right_letter = 0;

 /* since one letter is already discovered */
 win          = length - 1;


 while(wrongTry != 0) {

     /* read from user */

     for(counter = 0; counter < length; ++counter) {

         if(hangmanOutput[counter] == '_'){

            if(upper(alphabetFromUser) == upper(hangmanWord[counter])) {

                hangmanOutput[counter] = hangmanWord[counter];

                right_letter = 1;

                ++win;

            }

        }

    if(win + 1 == length)
        /* win */

    wrongTry -= !right_letter;

    right_letter = 0;

}
```

I haven't tested the code, but it should work. Try to understand what I have changed and why.

EDIT: @Andrew Henle had mentioned in the comments that the OP hadn't specified the character set, therefore I assumed that It's ASCII.

Comment: The character set doesn't have to be ASCII.

Comment: IMHO, if I was the OP, **I would be surely be more confused** after reading that answer, than before posting my question in Stack Overflow. :/

Comment: @AndrewHenle true. Thanks for mentioning. I have edited my post.

Comment: @VioAriton I have tested your code. Even if I read the input of the user it dosen't enter the game

Answer (score 0):

For an ASCII only input, it is no brainer....Just exploit the fact that `char` type in C can in fact be used as `int` and do the maths.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  char ch;
  printf("letter : ");
  ch = getc(stdin);

  if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
    ch -=32;
  else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
    ch += 32;

  printf("output : %c\n", ch);

  return 0;
}
```

Another version is given below. You can replace `lower_case` and `upper_case` with any other alphabet you want and boom, it will work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char convert(char ch){
  const char *lower_case = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  const char *upper_case = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  char *p;

  if ((p = strchr(lower_case, ch)) != NULL)
    return *(upper_case+(p-lower_case));
  else if ((p = strchr(upper_case, ch)) != NULL)
    return *(lower_case+(p-upper_case));
  else
    return ch;
}

int main(){
  char ch;
  printf("letter : ");
  ch = getc(stdin);

  printf("output : %c\n", convert(ch));

  return 0;
}
```